# reshape en R en función de varias variables

Tags: r

tengo este conjunto de datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y quería generar variables nuevas cogiendo el  valor de la columna `x3` para cada color, de forma que el resultado final fuese el siguiente (variable nuevas: `x5`,`x6` y `x7`):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero no lo consigo porque cuando ejecuto esto:

```
ajuste = reshape(x,v.names='x3',idvar = 'color', timevar = 'x4',direction = 'wide')
```

Me sale este warning :

> Warning message: In reshapeWide(data, idvar = idvar, timevar =
>   timevar, varying = varying,  :   some constant variables (x1,x2) are
>   really varying

Y solo me pone una única fila de color y además se pierden variables. Resultado del R:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo resolver el problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reshape()` no creo que te vaya a servir para lo que estás intentando, de ninguna manera estás modificando el formato/orientación del `data.frame` original, simplemente estás agregando nuevas columnas con una cierta lógica, la cual sería:

- Una nueva columna por cada `color`
- Cada columna tendrá el valor de `x3` correspondiente a dicho `color`, que asumimos que es único pero lo tendrá a partir de la fila en que aparece dicho `color` hasta la última y en las filas anteriores completaremos con `NA` si corresponde.

Primero armamos un ejemplo más compacto de lo que planteas:

```
df <- data.frame(color=rep(c("azul", "amarillo", "rojo"),c(2,3,2)), 
                 x3=rep(c(0.45, 1.90, 0.12),c(2,3,2)))

df
     color   x3
1     azul 0.45
2     azul 0.45
3 amarillo 1.90
4 amarillo 1.90
5 amarillo 1.90
6     rojo 0.12
7     rojo 0.12
```

Ahora empezamos a armar las nuevas columnas:

```
colores <- unique(df[, c("color", "x3")])
colores <- cbind(colores, which(!duplicated(df$color)))
colores

     color   x3 which(!duplicated(df$color))
1     azul 0.45                            1
3 amarillo 1.90                            3
6     rojo 0.12                            6
```

`colores`  es un nuevo `data.frame` que construimos con la información que necesitaremos luego:

1. Tiene una fila por `color`
2. El valor correspondiente de `x3` (es fundamental que exista un único valor por `color` sino está solución no funcionaría adecuadamente)
3. El número de fila dónde aparece por primera vez dicho `color`

Ahora sí armamos las columnas que necesitamos:

```
m <- apply(colores, 
           MARGIN=1, 
           function(x) c(rep(NA, as.numeric(x[3])-1),rep(x[2], nrow(df)-(as.numeric(x[3])-1)))
           )
colnames(m) <- paste0("x", 5:(4+ncol(m)))
m

     x5     x6     x7    
[1,] "0.45" NA     NA    
[2,] "0.45" NA     NA    
[3,] "0.45" "1.90" NA    
[4,] "0.45" "1.90" NA    
[5,] "0.45" "1.90" NA    
[6,] "0.45" "1.90" "0.12"
[7,] "0.45" "1.90" "0.12"
```

Toda la magia la lleva `apply()` que aplicará por fila (`MARGIN=1`) una función: `c(rep(NA, as.numeric(x[3])-1),rep(x[2], nrow(df)-(as.numeric(x[3])-1)))`que genera el vector deseado para cada columna. Luego simplemente renombramos los nombres de las columnas `colnames(m) <- paste0("x", 5:(4+ncol(m)))` para que sean `x5`, `x6` y `x7`. Lo único que resta es combinar las columnas al `data.frame` original mediante `cbind()`:

```
df <- cbind(df, m)
df

     color   x3   x5   x6   x7
1     azul 0.45 0.45 <NA> <NA>
2     azul 0.45 0.45 <NA> <NA>
3 amarillo 1.90 0.45 1.90 <NA>
4 amarillo 1.90 0.45 1.90 <NA>
5 amarillo 1.90 0.45 1.90 <NA>
6     rojo 0.12 0.45 1.90 0.12
7     rojo 0.12 0.45 1.90 0.12
```

Comment: Genial!!!ha funcionado!Muchisimas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Intente hacerlo con `reshape` no creo que sea posible. Otra opción es usar `dplyr` y `tidyr`:

```
#Creamos un ejemplo como tus datos, pero con variables aleatorias
df<-data.frame(
  color=c("azul","azul","amarillo","amarillo","amarillo","rojo","rojo"),
  x1=rnorm(7,1,1.4),
  x2=rnorm(7,1,1.4),
  x3=rnorm(7,1,1.4),
  x4=rnorm(7,1,1.4)
)
df
     color        x1       x2         x3         x4
1     azul 0.2770255 1.177434  2.7852169 -3.0556443
2     azul 3.2693714 1.789661  1.2753546  1.8557427
3 amarillo 3.4960225 1.102697  0.2456760  3.5338329
4 amarillo 0.1830361 3.159952  4.5077288  1.8827527
5 amarillo 1.4162242 0.681532  0.9610655  1.2562143
6     rojo 3.0472798 2.046798 -1.0162360 -0.4893168
7     rojo 1.8818645 2.676713  0.1375999  1.7087433
#Usaremos estas dos librerias
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df$id<-1:nrow(df)#Agrego id

df2<-spread(df,color,x3)# Separamos la variable x3 por color

#Como el paso anterior elimina color y x3 usare el id para recrearlos
df2<-df2%>%arrange(id)# Ordenamos por id
df2$color<-df$color# Creamos color igual al original
df2$x3<-df$x3# lo mismo para x3

#Queda compleatr las variables azul, amarillo, y rojo
df2$azul<-df$x3# azul es igual que x3
# A amarillo le faltan los valores de rojo
df2$amarillo[df2$color=="rojo"]<-df2$rojo[df2$color=="rojo"]

#Ahora solo ordeno y renombro todo como en tu resultado deseado
df2<-select(df2,color,x1,x2,x3,x4,x5=azul,x6=amarillo,x7=rojo)
df2

     color        x1       x2         x3         x4         x5         x6         x7
1     azul 0.2770255 1.177434  2.7852169 -3.0556443  2.7852169         NA         NA
2     azul 3.2693714 1.789661  1.2753546  1.8557427  1.2753546         NA         NA
3 amarillo 3.4960225 1.102697  0.2456760  3.5338329  0.2456760  0.2456760         NA
4 amarillo 0.1830361 3.159952  4.5077288  1.8827527  4.5077288  4.5077288         NA
5 amarillo 1.4162242 0.681532  0.9610655  1.2562143  0.9610655  0.9610655         NA
6     rojo 3.0472798 2.046798 -1.0162360 -0.4893168 -1.0162360 -1.0162360 -1.0162360
7     rojo 1.8818645 2.676713  0.1375999  1.7087433  0.1375999  0.1375999  0.1375999
```